# Creating objects from an eventsource

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to store the date and the data from an event source to an object containing the `coreid` and continue to push the data and date to the correct `coreid` object.

As of now it's storing the `wifiData` to both of the `coreid`s instead of the corresponding one. How would I push the data to the right id?

```
    <template>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Probe Diagnostics</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <line-chart id="wifiChart" ytitle="Signal Strength" label="Wifi Strength" :colors="['#b00']" :messages="{empty: 'Waiting for data'}"
                    :data="wifiData" height="250px" :library="{backgroundColor: '#eee'}" :download="true" :min="-20"
                    :max="20"></line-chart>
                <column-chart :data="wifiData" ytitle="Signal Strength" height="250px"></column-chart>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <line-chart :data="psSoc" ytitle="ps-soc" height="250px"></line-chart>
                <line-chart :data="psVoltage" ytitle="ps-voltage" height="250px"></line-chart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    let wifiData = [];
    let psSoc = [];
    let psVoltage = [];
    let photons = {};
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                wifiData,
                psSoc,
                psVoltage,
                photons,
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.streamData();
        },
        methods: {
            streamData() {
                // LIVE PUSH EVENTS
                if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                    var eventSource = new EventSource(
                        "http://10.10.10.2:8020/v1/Events/?access_token=687b5aee0b82f6536b65f");
                    eventSource.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
                        console.log("Opened connection to event stream!");
                    }, false);

                    eventSource.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
                        console.log("Errored!");
                    }, false);

                    eventSource.addEventListener('WiFi Signal', function (e) {
                        var parsedData = JSON.parse(e.data);

                        if (parsedData.coreid in photons) {
                            photons[parsedData.coreid].push([parsedData.published_at, parsedData.data])

                            return
                        } else {
                            photons[parsedData.coreid] =[]
                        }
                    }, false);

                    eventSource.addEventListener('ps-soc', function (e) {
                        var parsedData = JSON.parse(e.data);
                        psSoc.push([parsedData.published_at, parsedData.data])
                    }, false);

                    eventSource.addEventListener('ps-voltage', function (e) {
                        var parsedData = JSON.parse(e.data);
                        psVoltage.push([parsedData.published_at, parsedData.data])
                    }, false);

                }

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `wifiData` completely. Instead just manage the array directly inside the lookup object:

```
 // Initialize if needed:
 if(!photons[parsedData.coreid])
   photons[parsedData.coreid] = [];

 // Then push directly to it:
 photons[parsedData.coreid].push(/*...*/);
```

Comment: I added the rest of the code to my initial question. The reason I'm using a wifiData variable is because i'm rendering charts off of it. I can't use an object that doesn't exist yet when mounting the charts so it'll throw an error.